# Firebase cloud functions - TypeError: Cannot read property '___' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase

Os explico mi problema, he realizado una función para firebase para cuando se inserte, en este caso, un bando nuevo en `Firebase Firestone`, la función envie una notificacion a los usuarios. El problema está cuando intento obtener el id del documento ya que le necesito. He seguido los ejemplos que vienen en la documentación y tal y como lo hago me sale este error al intentar leer el id:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'bando' of undefined
>       at exports.bandoCreado.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/user_code/index.js:17:30)
>       at Object. (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
>       at next (native)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
>       at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:700:26
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Que viene de esta linea en concreto:

```
const idBando=event.params.bando;
```

Os dejo la función completa por si aún así hay alguna duda, un saludo.

```
 exports.bandoCreado = functions.firestore
.document('bandos/{bando}')
.onCreate((event) =>{
    const idBando=event.params.bando;

    var datos=event.data.data();

    var titulon=datos.titulo;
    var contenidon=datos.contenido;
    var f_empiecen=datos.f_empiece;
    var f_finn=datos.f_fin;
    var t_stampn=datos.t_stamp;

    const payload={
        data: {
            titulo: titulon,
            mensaje: contenidon,
            id: idBando,
            f_empiece: f_empiecen,
            f_fin: f_finn,
            t_stamp: t_stampn
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notificaciones",payload)
        .then(function(response) {
        // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
        // contents of response.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        return "";
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        return "";
      });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El día 3 de abril se liberó la nueva versión de API de Cloud Functions y hubo algunos cambios.

En tu caso particular, el trigger:

`.onCreate((event) =>{});`

cambió a

`.onCreate((userMetadata, context) => {});`

Y es ahora el argumento `context` el que tiene la propiedad `params` que intentas utilizar.

En el siguiente link puedes ver lo cambios realizados a la API respecto a Firestore:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#cloudfirestore